# Shrew wont connect after windows 8.1 upgrade

Tags: vpn, windows-8.1

I am using Shrew for my VPN connection on Windows 8.0 successfully but it stopped working properly after I upgraded to Windows 8.1. It connects to VPN ok but I cannot access anything on the network. After several attempts it disconnects. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling with no affect.

Any help wild be appreciated.
Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3):

What version are you using?

When 8.1 was pushed to me here, my copy of Shrew 2.2.2 Professional stopped connecting entirely, with a "tunnel disabled" message (there were 3 messages, that's the only one I can remember). It also hosed my Virtual Machine networking.

To fix, I uninstalled my VMs (VirtualBox, etc.), rebooted, re-installed Shrew, rebooted, and then reintalled VMs. Now everything is working correctly.

HTH!

Comment: Uninstalling Shrew 2.2.2 Standard and re installing fixed my problem as well. Thanks Mike!

Comment: Same here: simply uninstalling and reinstalling 2.2.2 Standard fixed it, even without reboot.

Answer (score -1):

I saw the same behaviour of Shrew on my machine; uninstalling, re-installing, manually deleting drivers and settings etc. didn't help.

As described [here](http://san.schausberger.cc/2013/11/vpn-problems-with-windows-8-1-and-shrew-vpn-client/), I use [TheGreenBow VPN Client](http://www.thegreenbow.com/vpn/vpn.html) now as an alternative, which works fine under Win 8.1.